# AWS easy way to provision a new database on an existing RDS (MariaDB) instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb, rds, amazon-cloudformation

I have a greenfields account, with a bunch of stacks I've built a-top of it. Now, I have no existing EC2 instances, however while "in this state" I want to connect to my existing RDS MariaDB instance and create a new database and user.

Since I have no instances to connect from and I don't want to "just start one" I was hoping for some advice on a way I could neatly "wrap up" this simple bash/mysql command into a simple deployable package (a "create database and user" package of sorts).

If I could do it with cloudformation would be great, but is there a way to perform such an action, also parameterised.

I've played with Datapipeline in the past and know I could use it to run an ec2 instance, run a script and then shut down... but, that seems heavy and not sure how the params part could work.

Basically, just looking for advice from people with stronger AWS knowledge than I.

Comment: You can do almost anything in AWS with lambda, and it has a free tier so it won't cost anything. You can also enable remote access to your database from outside AWS and use any tool you like. CloudFormation takes parameters, but I don't know if you can create new databases / users with it - I suspect not.

Comment: Building on @Tim's idea; you could create an [AWS::SecretsManager::Secret](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-secretsmanager-secret.html), which can generate a random password, and then have a Lambda function that reads the username and password values and initializes your MariaDB instance. It's also worth noting that Aurora Serverless MySQL has a [Data API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-data-api-for-amazon-aurora-serverless/) and a Python Lambda function could interact with only boto3 (instead of bundling MySQL libraries).